# Bing background as desktop wallpaper

Tags: python

I wrote following code to set bing background as desktop wallpaper in windows 10 using Python 2.7 . The problem is sometimes the image is not properly downloading and in such cases default wallpaper is being set.When this happens the image file is being saved in the required directory but when I try to open it I get a message in Picture Viewer, "we can't open this file". I don't understand why this happening.

```
import re
import os
import time
import json
import requests
import urllib
import ctypes
import socket

def wallpaper():
 URL = "http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&idx=0&n=1"
 image_data = json.loads(requests.get(URL).text)
 image_url = 'http://www.bing.com' + image_data['images'][0]['url']
 image_download_url = 'http://www.bing.com/hpwp/' + image_data['images'][0]['hsh']
 image_name = image_url[re.search("rb/", image_url).end():re.search('_EN', image_url).start()] + '.jpg'
 filepath = "C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\Bing_Wallpapers" + "\\" + image_name
 urllib.urlretrieve(image_download_url, filename=filepath)
 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
 ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, filepath, 0)

def internet(host="8.8.8.8", port=53, timeout=3):
 try:
  socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect((host, port))
  return True
 except Exception as ex:
  print ex.message
  return False
try:
 wallpaper()
except:
 while(1):
     if(internet()):
         break
 wallpaper()
```

Comment: I strongly suspect a problem with Python interpreting the backslash ("\") character in string-literal as escape character.  Can't test though, so can't answer.  You may want to put the path elemenets in a raw string instead.  And don't use your Admin account for daily stuff.

Comment: Oh, and don't abuse Google DNS for the purpose it's not supposed to serve.